# Pull Image from Gitlab Registry in Docker Compose File

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I want to deploy a docker stack on my own server. I've written a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that currently builds the images in my stack and pushes them to my gitlab registry:

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:stable
  services: 
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker info
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE1_TAG -f dir1/Dockerfile ./dir1
    - docker push $DOCKER_IMAGE1_TAG
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE2_TAG -f dir2/Dockerfile ./dir2
    - docker push $DOCKER_IMAGE2_TAG
```

I'm struggling for a way to run the `docker deploy` command on my own server with the `docker-compose.yml` file I've written, that successfully pulls the images from my gitlab registry. I figure I could use `sshpass` to `ssh` into my server and then copy the `docker-compose.yml` file across and run `docker deploy` from there, but I'm not sure what's the best way to allow my server to access the images now located in my `gitlab` registry:

```
# Need to ssh into the server, transfer over docker-stack file and run docker swarm deploy
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: production
  image: trion/ng-cli-karma
  before_script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sshpass
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

This is a section of my `docker-compse` file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  octeditor:
    image: image # how to set this to the image in my container registry?
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - front-tier
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
      failure_action: rollback
      placement:
        constraints:
          - 'node.role == manager'
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
```

How can I pull the images from my gitlab registry? Is this the preferred way of creating a docker deployment on a remote server, via gitlab ci?

Comment: You need to do docker login to GitLab on the server so that docker on the server can pull the image from GitLab.... https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/ . The command you need to run is `docker login registry.example.com`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This sounds quite complicated to get right from a gitlab ci (I may be wrong however). Have you any examples of this in a .gitlab-ci.yml file? I can't seem to locate one on the Gitlab site.

Comment: The [link](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/) I shared has an example of `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. You do not required to use that file. You just need to run `docker login` command against gitlab registry on server before you run docker-compose command on the server.

Answer (score 12):

I equally had this difficulty recently, finally I found out that the solution is just to insert the link to the image in the private registry as is the case for me with gitlab.

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  octeditor:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/project-or-group/project-name/image-name:tag
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - front-tier
```